# AppEngine Java caching files

Tags: javascript, java, css, google-app-engine, caching

When I run my site on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights
I get the recommendation - Take advantage of browser caching for these resources with appropriate options and all my css and js are included there.
I used the following configuration in the appengine-web.xml but nothing seems to happen:

```
  <static-files>
    <include path="/**.png" expiration="1d" />
    <include path="/css/*.css" expiration="1d" />
    <include path="/js/*.js" expiration="1d" />
    <include path="/**.js" expiration="1d" />

</static-files>
```

Let me know if you need further clarifications. I do this because my outgoing traffic is getting close to 1 GB after about 10k pages views and from what I understood I should be able to have about 160k views easily..

Comment: Is PageSpeed Insight not considering `1d` long enough or are your changes not reflected at all after re-deploying + re-testing (i.e. does it still says your files expire in 10 minutes or does it now say your files expire in 1 day)? Are the files shown under `Show how to fix` -> `Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources` covered by your `appengine-web.xml` expiration rules?

Comment: actually they are no longer shown exceprt for google javascripts but when I reload the page the resources are still taken from the server and not from the cache and the browser should take them from the cache right?

Comment: How are you determining that the files are taken from the server? Are you seeing that in GAE logs or in your browser's DevTools? Say, in Chrome, if you open DevTools and use the Network tab, do you see the `(from cache)` value in the `Size` column when you reload the page at all?

Comment: From chrome devtools network tab I don't see from cache value but the size of the css and js files. When I see the http header values are correct in ms maybe I miss some http header, I can provide you with full copy of the values

Comment: Sure, go ahead and update the post to include the full response from the server.

Comment: I believe the problem is Cache-Control:max-age=0 and Pragma:no-cache
values see:

`Request URL:http://MYURL/js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:216.58.212.17:80
Response Headers
view source
***Cache-Control:public, max-age=2592000**
Date:Wed, 16 Mar 2016 17:51:57 GMT
ETag:"eYxQVw"
Expires:Fri, 15 Apr 2016 17:51:57 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
**Cache-Control:max-age=0**
Connection:keep-alive
**Pragma:no-cache**`